# what is one time purchase in officejs for add-ins

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins, office-js-helpers

just visited the [this URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability#see-also) for office add-in availability.

What is one time purchase in office add-ins and office 365 subscription ones?

[image: office add-in availability screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- One time purchase: Pay a single, one-time cost

Office 2019 is sold as a one-time purchase, which means you pay a single, up-front cost to get Office apps for one computer. One-time purchases are available for both PCs and Macs. However, there are no upgrade options which means if you plan to upgrade to the next major release, you'll have to buy it at full price.

- Office 365 subscription: Pay a small monthly fee, or save by paying for a full year

Office 365 is a subscription service that ensures you always have the most up-to-date modern productivity tools from Microsoft. There are Office 365 plans for home and personal use, as well as for small and midsized businesses, large enterprises, schools, and non-profits.

A detail difference can be found at 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-s-the-difference-between-office-365-and-office-2019-ed447ebf-6060-46f9-9e90-a239bd27eb96

Comment: Thanks Raymond for quick reply. but i like to know does this information will be blocker for our officejs add-in development and deployment? or will that works fine.

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question, could you please explain a bit more what does it mean for blocker for add-in development?

Comment: Blocker means wanted to know whether any office js api stopped working suddenly due to office 365 subscription / in app purchase service?

Comment: I dont think we would suddenly block our customers from API layer.